# deleting a char array with cast to char*?

Tags: c++

Which of these should be used?

```
char *ex = new char[255];
// code
delete [] ex;
```

or

```
char *ex = new char[255];
// code
delete [] (char *) ex;
```

I'm thinking that the cast isn't necessary, but would it have any effect on the actual deletion?

Comment: The cast does nothing, but even if it did your two examples would still behave the same because the type of the operand to `delete[]`  is `char*` in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *ex = new char[255];
// code
delete [] ex;
```

You do not need to cast, The cast won't have any effect anyways.

The C++ Standard does not need you to do any casting. Here is the reference.

**Section §3.7.3.2.3:**

> The value of the first argument supplied to one of the deallocation functions provided in the standard library may be a null pointer value; if so, the call to the deallocation function has no effect. **Otherwise, the value supplied to `operator delete(void*)` in the standard library shall be one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either `operator new(size_t)` or `operator new(size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)` in the standard library, and the value supplied to operator `delete[](void*)` in the standard library shall be one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either `operator new[](size_t)` or `operator new[](size_t, const std::nothrow_t&)` in the standard library.**

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessary and would have no effect. You are casting a `char*` to a `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

delete[] destroys (or destructs) a number of objects and then frees the memory. If the type is not an object, it simply frees the memory without calling destructors. This would be good:

```
 class some_class
 {
       some_class(int);
 };

 ....
 some_class *p = new some_class[[2]](0)(1);

 delete[] p; // delete calculates how many objects where created, and call destructors of all objects, then frees the memory (which is twice sizeof(some_class)
```